# How to add pinned shortcuts to Kids Corner

Tags: amber-update, nokia-lumia-1020

I am trying to set up Kids Corner to do something useful. With many apps, one can pin "shortcuts" or certain options from the app to the Start Screen e.g. with many of the Battery apps, you can pin the shortcuts to Bluetooth, wifi etc to launch directly from the Start Screen.

I would like to set up my Kids Corner as my TV Scheduler. I have added the TV Show app to the KC, and would like to pin several shows there as well. From the normal menu, I can pin the TV show to the Start Screen, but obviously this cannot be done from inside the KC. Is there a way to add the pinned shortcut from the Start Screen to Kids Corner?

Comment: I highly doubt it, Kids Corner is a special area where you can add apps from a list - but apps can't pin secondary tiles there as they are only aware of one Start Menu

Comment: Ah was afraid that would be the answer. Just thought I would be able use the KC for something useful to me, now I won't even use it.